# Can I access to Alerts Object of OWASP ZAP?

Tags: owasp, zap

In Stand Alone Script, how can I access to Alerts Object (mean get all info of Alerts show in the screenshot below)?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just submitted a PR for the ZAP community-scripts for a script that does this :)
https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/pull/100/files

```
extAlert = org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control.getSingleton().
    getExtensionLoader().getExtension(
        org.zaproxy.zap.extension.alert.ExtensionAlert.NAME) 
if (extAlert != null) {
    var Alert = org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.Alert
    var alerts = extAlert.getAllAlerts()
    for (var i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
        var alert = alerts[i]
        print (alert.uri)
        print ('\tName:\t' + alert.name)
        print ('\tRisk:\t' + Alert.MSG_RISK[alert.risk])
        print ('\tConfidence:\t' + Alert.MSG_CONFIDENCE[alert.confidence])
        // For more alert properties see https://static.javadoc.io/org.zaproxy/zap/2.7.0/org/parosproxy/paros/core/scanner/Alert.html
    }
}
```

Comment: For info this PR has been approved and the code is now part of the repo: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/master/standalone/Loop%20through%20alerts.js

Comment: Hi @Simon Bennetts
This is awesome. However, I have other problem with waiting for alerts object complete. I mean when you scan a site with a lot of URL, after scanning done, alerts object need time to update ( you can see the number of errors increase in real time) so if you run the standalone script when the above process is not done yet - the result is wrong ==> we need to check this status complete or not, how can?

Thanks,

Comment: That will be the passive scan thread. You can check hom many more records are left to scan using:


print(org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control.getSingleton().
        getExtensionLoader().getExtension(        org.zaproxy.zap.extension.pscan.ExtensionPassiveScan.NAME).
            getRecordsToScan());

When that gets to zero then there are no records left to scan.

Note that if any more requests are proxied through ZAP then they will be added to the queue and that count will go up again.